# Issue with file ACLs for /var/log/audit/audit.log

Tags: acl, linux-audit

I have a service account that requires access to `/var/log/audit/audit.log` and since this user shouldn't be part of the `root` group nor do I want to change the ownership or group of the file, I decided to implement file ACLs.

The issue is that when `auditd` rotates the file, the rotated file does not have the expected file ACL according to the man pages `acl(5)` and `setfacl(1)`.

This is the file ACL for the parent directory, including the default ACL:

```
> getfacl /var/log/audit
# file: var/log/audit
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:srv_usr:r-x
group::---
mask::r-x
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:srv_usr:r--
default:group::---
default:mask::r--
default:other::---
```

When `auditd` rotates the file the ACL becomes:

```
> getfacl /var/log/audit/audit.log
# file: var/log/audit/audit.log
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
user:srv_usr:r--                 #effective:---
group::---
mask::---
other::---
```

As you can see, the effective permissions is that the account is not allowed to do anything.

What leads me to believe something weird is happening is that when I create a file in that path as root manually, the following ACL is applied:

```
> touch /var/log/audit/test
> getfacl /var/log/audit/test
# file: var/log/audit/test
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
user:srv_usr:r--
group::---
mask::r--
other::---
```

This ACL matches the documentation in `acl(5)` that says:

> The new object inherits the default ACL of the containing directory as its access ACL.

The file ACL matches the default ACL of `/var/log/audit`.

What's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that Linux ACL store the mask using the group permission bits.

Upon rotation, the permissions for the group are removed because auditd is not ACL-aware and believe it is setting permissions for the group. Thus the mask becomes empty (`mask::---`) and the effective permissions are null (`#effective:---`).

See also this question: [What relationships tie ACL mask and standard group permission on a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147499/what-relationships-tie-acl-mask-and-standard-group-permission-on-a-file)